# MERN Axios/Express/Mongoose issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I'm sure this issue has been discovered and figured out before, but I'm having trouble with it so please be gentle. I'm self-teaching React/Node and decided to make a MERN CRUD system. I'm having issue with the update portion of the code and I'm not sure how to fix it. For the time being (I can update as necessary), my axios call is:

```
axios.put('/api/items/' + selectComponent, {
          Quantity: quantityInput.value
        })
          .then((response) => {
            setItems(previous => previous.map((item) => {
              if (item.Item === selectComponent) {
                return { ...item, Quantity: response.data }
              }
              else {
                return item
              }
            }))
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          });
```

The schema for the entries in the MongoDB is

```
  _id: String,
  Item: String,
  unit:String,
  Quantity:Number,
  Reorder: Number,
});
```

And the backend is:

```
const InvItem = mongoose.model('InventoryItems', schema);

app.get('/api/items/:Item', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const item = await InvItem.findOneAndUpdate(
      { Item: req.params.Item },
    );
    if (!item) {
      return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Item not found' });
    }
    res.send(item);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

app.put('/api/items/:Item', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const items = await InvItem.findOneAndUpdate(
  { Item: req.params.Item },
  { $inc: { Quantity: -quantity } },
  { new: true }
    );
    if (!items) {
      return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Item not found' });
    }
    res.send(items);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  } 
});
```

Anything I can think to try is always returning an AxiosError500 and I'm not sure what I'm doing. Be gentle, I'm new....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast `Quantity`:

```
app.put('/api/items/:Item', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { Quantity } = req.body;
    if (isNaN(+Quantity)) {
      return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Quantity must be a number' });
    }
    const items = await InvItem.findOneAndUpdate(
      { Item: req.params.Item },
      { $inc: { Quantity: -parseInt(Quantity) } },
      { new: true }
    );
    if (!items) {
      return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Item not found' });
    }
    res.send(items);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'd be lying if I said I understood what was happening behind the scenes (and PLEASE feel free to educate me... I'm trying to genuinely learn), but it worked!

Comment: You were referring to `quantity` instead of `req.body.Quantity` (as already suggested by @abonda. The casting should actually not matter, you were probably passing a non-numeric or non-well-formatted value.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, your quantity should be coming out of the body of the request. You might need to change

```
{ $inc: { Quantity: -quantity } },
```

to

```
{ $inc: { Quantity: -req.body.Quantity } },
```

Comment: My goal is to decrement the quantity based on a number input by the user in an input field. The issue I run into is how to pass the parameter entered by the user into the $inc field. Or is that what your suggestion does?

Comment: Yep! Assuming that `quantityInput.value` from your frontend holds the value and that you have a json body parser on the backend.

Comment: Still getting that error....